# Stationary Heat Equation with Convective Boundary Conditions

Tags: thermodynamics, greens-functions, convection

Let's say that I know a fundamental solution for the Laplace equation in the whole plane: 
$$\nabla^2u(\mathbf{x})=\delta\quad \text{in the sense of distributions}$$
And I need a solution for the laplace equation in the semiplane $x>0$. 
I know that if there are Dirichlet homogeneous conditions on the boundary:
$$u(\mathbf{x})=0\quad\mathbf{x}=(0,y)$$ 
I can construct a solution $u_\mathrm{D}$ in that semiplane satisfiying the condition by setting:

$$u_\mathrm{D}(x)=u(x)-u(-x) \quad \forall\mathbf{x}=(x,y);x>0 $$

I know I can do the same for homogeneous Neumann conditions:
$$u'(\mathbf{x})=0\quad \mathbf{x}=(0,y)$$
then the function 
$$u_\mathrm{N}=u(x)+u(-x) $$
will also solve the problem on the on the semi plane with the Neumann boundary condition.

My question is: Can I do the same for homogeneous Robin boundary conditions i.e.:
$$ u(\mathbf{x})+Au'(\mathbf{x})=0 \quad \mathbf{x}=(0,y) $$

and if it is possible, who would be de expression?

Thank you

Comment: What is $\delta$? Do you mean $\delta(\mathbf x)$ — Dirac delta centered at origin?

Comment: yes, exactly that, I didn't put $\delta(\mathbf{x})$ because I didn't want to begin a discussion about if it is a function or not.